# Significantlly different from zero at the 1% and 5% level of significance

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

You want to estimate a logistic regression model in which you want to explain if a person is employed (= variable “employed”, 0 if unemployed and 1 if employed) with with the work experience of the individual in years (= variable “experience”). The coefficients of the model yield the following output

```
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(> |z|)
(Intercept)         −2.00     1.00      −2.00   0.046
experience           0.50     0.20       2.50   0.012
```

Correct statements:
The coefficient of “experience” is not significantly different from zero at the 1% significance level.

The coefficient of “experience” is significantly different from zero at the 5% significance level.

The intercept is not significantly different from zero at the 1% significance level.

The intercept is significantly different from zero at the 5% significance level.

Why are these statements correct?

Assumptions: Critical values of the (two-sided) t- and z-statistics at the 1%, 5% and 10% significance levels are 2.58, 1.96, and 1.64, respectively.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What are the p-values and z-stats?

Answer (score 7):

Graham Wright's answer is good (+1) but leaves out quite a lot of material that may be of interest. I'll attempt to add some of that.

One of the main reasons that we have 'cutoffs' like 0.05 and 0.01 is that the original proponent of p-values, RA Fisher, worked from tables of critical values with columns of 0.05 and 0.01 etc. That allowed him to avoid long hours of manual calculation. Nowadays we can almost always calculate p-values with good precision at no effort and so there is no reason to say that a p-value is less than any arbitrary cutoff instead of simply saying what the p-value is. Your statements about the coefficients is wordy and does not communicate as much information as a simple statement of the p-values! Why they might be correct depends on context and on your inferential intent.

The 'significant' moniker is problematical because it is attached to two distinctly different approaches: the (neo)-Fisherian significance test approach where the p-value is used as an index of the evidence against a null hypothesis in the data, according to the statistical model; and the Neyman–Pearsonian hypothesis test approach that focusses on the long run error rates associated with the method rather than the evidence from any particular dataset. Many people think that it is OK to use a hybrid of the two approaches, but that leads to logical and practical difficulties.

The (neo)-Fisherian framework needs no statements of whether a result is significant (or not) at some cutoff because a result with p=0.012 is significant at the 0.012 level. The above and below are arithmetical truths that follow from that. I will note that p=0.012 in many circumstances indicates a moderate sort of strength of evidence against the null hypothesis according to the statistical model. Not enough to be compelling, but enough to make a follow-up experiment interesting. That is the meaning that Fisher ascribed to his 'significant'.

In the Neyman–Pearsonian framework it is necessary to decide on the cutoffs for 'significance' in advance of the experiment or, at least in advance of data inspection. If you did not do that then your results can only really be 'significant' with $\alpha$ at the highest level that you might have used. In that way your statement that (It is sometimes assumed that 0.05 is that highest level but I find the whole idea of trying to half-apply the Neyman–Pearsonian methods silly.)

There is far more that can be written here, but I have published a few papers on the topic that are aimed at inexperienced users of statistical tests, and so I will point you towards a couple that freely available. I suggest that you read them in the order given.

1. [Bad statistical practice in pharmacology (and other basic biomedical disciplines): you probably don't know P](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3419900/)
2. [A Reckless Guide to P-values: Local Evidence, Global Errors](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286)

Comment: *"A Reckless Guide to P-values: Local Evidence, Global Errors"* is a fabulous paper !!

Comment: @VivekSharma I'm glad that you like it! Writing it made a lot of things clear to me, perhaps at the wrong end of my career...

Comment: @MichaelLew your Reckless Guide .... article is excellent!

Comment: @GrahamBornholt Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This is a question about what "p values" (what your program calls "Pr(> |z|") represents. Your *estimate* for the coefficient for experience is .05. The p value of .012 tells you that, if the *true* value for the coefficient really were zero, there is only a 1.2% probability that you would have (incorrectly) estimated a value as far away from zero as 0.5 (assuming various other things about the sample and model specification). Likewise the p value for the intercept is .046, meaning that there is a 4.6% probability that, if the true intercept was zero, you would have estimated a value as far away from zero as -2.

"Significance levels" are just conventional (some might say arbitrary) "cutoffs" for p values to help us to decide when to call a result "statistically significant." So a 5% significance level means a p value lower than .05. It's more common to see this referred to as a 95% *confidence* level, because (since 100%-5%=95%) it implies that we have "95% confidence" (in a very technical sense of that word) that the result is not due to sampling error. The 1% significance level is for results with p values below .01. This is a higher level of confidence - we can be not just 95% but 99% "confident" that results significant at this level are not due to sampling error.

Here *both* of your results are statistically significant at the 5% level (p values below .05), but *neither* p value is below .01 so neither result is significant at the 1% level. Alternatively, you could say that you are  95% (but *not* 99%) confident confident that both values are different from zero.

Annoying caveats: First, note that the p value only tells you the probability of a result being wrong due to sampling error, and only assuming a number of (potentially unrealistic) assumptions about the sample and model and other stuff. Second, the word "confidence" really does have a very technical and somewhat counter intuitive meaning in this context, although it is close enough to the way we normally use the term in English to be mostly applicable.